# Visualforce error placeholder

Tags: error-messages

The error on my page is covering the label of the form.

Is there a way to position the error message in a specific place?

See image of the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEO9e.png

Some code:

```
<div class="lp-pom-form-field clearfix" style="width: 349px; height: 41px; top: 427px;">

<label for="sort_code" class="main" style="top: 0px;">Sort Code</label>

<apex:inputField value="{!CurrentContact.C_Sort_Code__c}" style="top: 19px; left: 0px; width: 339px; font-size: 15px; line-height: 15px; height: 15px; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;"/>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll want to use the `apex:message` tag ([docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_message.htm)) which can be used to display error messages related to an input tag.  There is a [fantastic SFSE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/8140/594) by @JesseAltman differentiating the various messaging options that shows how this works.

Comment: It seems Apex:message uses default style, that cannot be overridden? I think I need to use addError, which looks a bit too complicated.

Comment: Apex:message is pretty bare bones, take a look at the example in the docs with uses the styleclass attribute to control the error message look and feel.