# How to write code to display all user-friendly error messages on the UI for Apex / Visualforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, pagemessages, errormessages

Visualforce page is displaying one error message at a time not all error messages if validation is failed for all fields.Below is my code in the controller.I have apex:pagemessages in visualforce page is display error messages

```
if((newFR.Fleet_Vehicle_Maintained__c == 'No')&& (newFR.Fleet_Explanation__c == NULL )) {
          newFR.Fleet_Explanation__c.addError('If the fleet vehicle is not being maintained by the rep, an explanation is required.');
                        return null;
          }
         if((newFR.Rep_Policy__c == 'No')&& (newFR.Not_Policy_Explanation__c == NULL )) {
           newFR.Not_Policy_Explanation__c.addError('Not_Following_Policy_Explanation__c');

          return null;
          } 
          if((newFR.FR_Status__c == 'Send for Representative')&& (newFR.Review_Date__c > system.today() )) {
           newFR.Review_Date__c.addError('Review Date cannot be a future date when sending  for acknowledgement.');

          return null;
          }
```

Comment: which VF message tag are you using?

Comment: apex:pagemessages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code you've produced is quitting after the first error (`return null`). A more usual scenario is to set a flag when validation fails, then check for the flag at the end of the validation to abort processing.

Here's a common example:

```
public PageReference doSomething() {
    Boolean okayToSave = true;
    if( condition1 ) {
        record.field1__c.addError(...);
        okayToSave = false;
    }
    if( condition2 ) {
        record.field2__c.addError(...);
        okayToSave = false;
    }
    if( conditionN ) {
        record.fieldN__c.addError(...);
        okayToSave = false;
    }
    if( !okayToSave ) {
        return null;
    }
    // Now save the data
    insert record;
    return Page.SuccessfulSave;
}
```

Of course, I left out the part where you use a try-catch block or other error handling for the actual save, because it's not relevant to what I'm trying to explain.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the addError field which relates to the `<apex:message>` and `<apex:messages>` tags.  If you want use your existing code then you would need to use somethign like this

```
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'This is apex:pageMessages'));
```

or you could change your vf tag to `<apex:messages>` and it should work with your apex code.

Jesse Altman has an excellent answer on here for this very subject.  I would take a look at it.  It really helped me to understand the difference.  This explanation is the only place I have seen them all compared in one place and is an excellent resource.

[Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce)

Comment: Are you sure that's the case?  I thought addError shows up in pageMessages, next to inputField if adding error to a field, and in message component for an inputField.  The messages component is the same as pagemessages just without formatting.  (At least that's my understanding).

Comment: I went through the post but I have question.adderror method points to the field just like validation error on the field whereas apexpages.addmessage doesn't.Is there a way to use apexpages.addmessage to point to the field

Comment: adderror shows up in pagemessages but not all error messages at a time

Comment: Didn't you notice how he's aborting after the first error? That's why only one shows up.

Comment: lol....wow.  No i didn't.  Yikes.  Good catch