# How to update custom(another) field value if field default value is changed

Tags: apex, visualforce

The requirement is On the std layout of opportunity,there is a field probability which has some default value based on the stage that you use.
When I modify the default value of probability,I have to display a Waring message on screen. e.g.At Initial Stage Probability Value is 10% i have to change it 15%.As soon as I change to 15%,it should display some warning message which will display via inline VF.

for this I have written below code:

```
public static void probabilityDefaultValueChange(List<Opportunity>opt,Map<Id,Opportunity> optt)
     {
         List<Id>oppIds=new List<Id>();     

             for(Opportunity o:opt)
             {
                 if(o.Probability!=null && o.Id!=null && optt.get(o.Id).Probability!=10 )
                 {

                    oppIds.add(o.Id); 

                 }

             }


         List<Opportunity>opToUpdate=[Select Id,StageName,Probability,Custom_Probability_Change__c from Opportunity where Id in:oppIds];
         for(Opportunity o1:opToUpdate)
         {
             o1.Custom_Probability_Change__c=true;
         }
        Update opToUpdate;
     }
```

Custom_Probability_Change__c is a checkbox field That I have to send it Inline VF in order to display warning message and the condition optt.get(o.Id).Probability!=10  it checks whether Probability default value is default(10% here) or not.If i change default value(10%) to 15% it should update Custom_Probability_Change__c checkbox field to true.But it is not updating checkbox field value.

Can someone please guide what I am missing in this code?

Also I am new to VF page and not sure how to pass the Field value to VF page to display  warning message(**In this case I will send Custom_Probability_Change__ value to VF and once it checkbox field value is true,it displays warning message**).It would be great if someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing something like this  ?

Apex:
`

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert, after update, before insert, before update, before delete, after delete) {
    if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore) {
            OpportunityTriggerController.probabilityDefaultValueChange(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
    }
}


public class OpportunityTriggerController {
    public static void probabilityDefaultValueChange(List<Opportunity> lstOpportunity, Map<Id,Opportunity> mapOld) {
        for(Opportunity objOpportunity : lstOpportunity) {
            if(objOpportunity.Probability != mapOld.get(objOpportunity.Id) && mapOld.get(objOpportunity.Id).Probability == 10) {
                objOpportunity.addError('Default Opportunity Probability has changed');
            }   
        }
       }
}
```

`
Since method is called on before update, you dont need to call to update

```
update lstOpportunity;
```

VForce:
`<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i modify in my existing code?

Comment: @ransommule: you can't use apex page message in trigger.

Comment: you are right..  you should use objOpportunity.addError('Your custom error message');

Answer (score 0):

First of all you code has some issues, kindly consider the below code:

**Apex**

```
public static void probabilityDefaultValueChange(List<Opportunity>opt)
{
    List<Opportunity>opToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();     
    // why do you have a map of opp and a list of opp? consider using one. 
    for(Opportunity o:opt)
    {
        if(o.Probability!=null && o.Id!=null && o.Probability!=10 )
        {
            Opportunity opp = new opportunity();
            opp.Custom_Probability_Change__c = true;        
            opToUpdate.add(opp); 
        }
    }

    /* below code not required, but make sure you query "Custom_Probability_Change__c" field in your map or list
        List<Opportunity>opToUpdate=[Select Id,StageName,Probability,Custom_Probability_Change__c from Opportunity where Id in:oppIds];
        for(Opportunity o1:opToUpdate)
        {
            o1.Custom_Probability_Change__c=true;
        }
        */
    Update opToUpdate;
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page>
       <apex:form>
         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedItem}" onchange="callMethod()">
           <apex:selectOption value="{!itemList}"
         </apex:selectList>
       <apex:actionfunction name="callMethod" action="{!controllerMethod}" oncomplete="showAlert({!returnValue })"/>
      <apex:form>
  <script>
    function showAlert(t) {
      if(t) {
        alert('Correct');
      } else {
        alert('No value entered !');
      } 
    }
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

You should change the VF page `script` code to match your needs. But this should give you a head-start.

Above VF page code is courtesy of this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28728/alert-message-on-vf-page). Thanks to Ashwini.

Comment: It is not updating the value.

Comment: Exact code might not work, since I dont know from where "probabilityDefaultValueChange" method is called and what is being passed to it. I made those amends to give you an idea on how to write efficient code and conform to the best practices.