# Custom errors using apex:pageMessages

Tags: customer-portal, error-messages, pagemessages

I have created a custom Login page for my customer portal but the problem is that if I want errors to display when the user enters wrong credentials I am forced to use `<apex:pageMessages id="error" />` but this breaks a few styling elements on the page. I have looked into `<apex:pageMessage />`but they always display. Per Salesforce,

> This pageMessage will always display. Validation error 
>              messages appear in the pageMessages component.

So my question is how can I display my own error messages using `<apex:pageMessage />` or control the styling of `<apex:pageMessages />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will not try to reproduce the excellent answer already provided by @JesseAltman, but I believe this will help you do whatever you need around your error messages.

It goes over each messaging option (In a ridiculous amount of detail).  Also goes over the caveats of each, which does include styling.  I would take a look.

[Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce)