# Raising friendly user error from trigger context

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, triggercontext, adderror

I have after update trigger on contact.
I am trying to write a friendly error to screen whenever x is happening.(in apex code)
I followed this explanation: 
[Difference between the multiple messaging options in Visualforce?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8139/difference-between-the-multiple-messaging-options-in-visualforce)
and this one: 
https://albasfdc.com/2017/04/17/demystifying-adderror/
Are they still relvant?

When i Use just adderror from trigger context, nothing breaks and no error is thrown to screen.(maybe i should use vf Page? couldn't make it work... what should be the standrdcontroller, anyway to rerender after saving contact record)
When i do something like:

```
trigger triggerTry on contact(after update){
   list<string>contactIds = new list<string>();
   for(Contact contact: trigger.new){
    contactIds.add(contact.id);
}
   list<contact> contacts = [select id from contact where id in : contactIds];
   contacts[0].adderror('error');
}
```

I get something like:
caused by: System.Exception: SObject row does not allow errors".

Any simple example for this situation?(Raising friendly user error from trigger context)

Comment: you have to use the addError directly on the contacts included in the Trigger.new list. Your soql query is useless.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use adderror method to show the custom error message either in record level or at field level. Please refer the below code for reference

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after update) {

for (Account acct: Trigger.new) {
    acct.Name.addError('Error added to Name on trigger');
    acct.addError('Error added to account on trigger');
    }
}
```

[image: Output]